# Exif Orientation Image in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, exif, exif-js

I am using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-exif-orientation-img` package and images doesn't get displayed correctly in react.js

Checked on chrome and mozilla but doesn't seem to work.

`image-orientation` css property works only in Chrome so using library.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ExifOrientationImg from 'react-exif-orientation-img';
import { Grid, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const orientations = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    const images = [2];

    return (
      <div>

        <Grid fluid>

         <Row className="show-grid">
            {
              images.map(index =>
                <Col xs={3}>
                  <ExifOrientationImg
                    key={`demo_${index}`} className={'img-responsive'} 
                    src={`https://testexif.blob.core.windows.net/exifimages/${index}.jpg`}
                  />
                </Col>
            )}
          </Row>

          <Row className="show-grid">
            {
              orientations.map(index =>
                <Col xs={3}>
                  <ExifOrientationImg
                    key={`l_${index}`} className={'img-responsive'} 
                    src={`https://testexif.blob.core.windows.net/exifimages/Landscape_${index}.jpg`}
                  />
                </Col>
            )}
          </Row>

        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

For demo purpose the url of images are hardcoded with different orientations.

Below is the output

[image]

**Output of all images should look like shown below.**

[image]

[Source Code Download](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuDctNtAhhg8jKdPGpQKbHx6IUsIEQ)

**Steps:**

- npm install
- yarn start

Comment: I think you'll have to specify what is wrong, and what you're looking for. Where is the problem exactly, and what's your expectation?

Comment: @Mackan sorry .. i have uploaded the output image which should look like basically the images are displayed just as it is not taking orientation into consideration.

Comment: @Mackan i have provided the source code link